# Keras TypeError: evaluate_generator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'steps'

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to test a Keras model after training it:

```
# test model
metrics = self.espa.evaluate_generator(generator=testing_sequence_generator,
                                       steps=batches)
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: evaluate_generator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'steps'
```

What confuses me is that `steps` is a valid argument, as per Keras' documentation:

Arguments:

- **generator**: Generator yielding tuples (inputs, targets) or (inputs,
  targets, sample_weights)
- **steps**: Total number of steps (batches of samples) to yield from
  generator before stopping.
- **max_q_size**: maximum size for the generator queue workers: maximum
  number of processes to spin up when using process based threading
- **pickle_safe**: if True, use process based threading. Note that because
  this implementation relies on multiprocessing, you should not pass
  non picklable arguments to the generator as they can't be passed
  easily to children processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the keywords and passing the arguments directly appears to fix the problem:

```
# test model
metrics = self.espa.evaluate_generator(testing_sequence_generator,
                                       batches)
```